# MySQL checking if something is already in a column

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to MySQL and don't really know how to check if in the column "friendCode" the same value already exist and if that's the case it should look if in the same row in the "watched" column the value "0" is. I have already managed to check whether the code exists in a row. I just don't know how to look for the second condition.

Here is a picture how the table looks like:

[image]

And here that what I already managed to do:

```
    public static boolean checkRow(String query) {

        boolean ret = false;
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            if (rs.next() && !rs.getString("watched").equals(0)) {
                ret = false;
            } else {
                ret = true;
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: You should probably also include the `query` that you are using.

Comment: `!rs.getString("watched").equals(0)` isn't going to work. You're getting a _String_ and comparing that to an _Integer_. Assuming the column is never null and always contains integers try `rs.getInt("watched") != 0` instead.

Comment: What is `query` parameter value? Why you don't execute `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tablename WHERE friendCode = @friendCode AND watched = 0`? This query will return one row with one column `cnt` which' value may be 0 (no row matched the conditions) or above (the amount of rows matched). Or even more optimal `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE friendCode = @friendCode AND watched = 0) AS cnt` which returns 1 or 0 (row matched exists or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you are not written any select query in this program. If you are calling from the main method just check and try the below steps.
2. In Given Table watched column have integer DataType data.
3. Your Compare to String type.
4. Try it my code it's working if you have any concern revert back to this comment.

   ```
   public static boolean checkRow(String query) {
        boolean ret = false;
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            if (rs.next() && rs.getString("watched")!=0) {
                ret = false;
            } else {
                ret = true;
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ret;
   }
   ```